# Как получить значение в input без отправки данных js?

Tags: php, javascript

Здравствуйте, мне нужно сделать в БД поле, где нужно указать процент %
Но таким образом, чтобы можно было или выбрать из списка, или ввести свой.
Вот такое поле должно быть
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пока только придумал так, чтобы записать значение в бд нужно его узнать с input`а до отправки и записать в переменную. Как это сделать средствами JS?

Comment: вообще ничего не понятно.что значит _сделать в БД поле_? что мешает проверять уже на сервере после отправки?

Answer (score 1):

На сколько понял, вам нужно что-то вроде этого:

```
<input type="number" name="percentage" min="0" max="100" id="some">
```

Функция, возвращает введенное число

```
function getPercent() {
  return document.querySelector('#some').value
}
```